# pandas DatetimeIndex from timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large list of timestamps in nanoseconds (can easily be converted to miliseconds). I now want to make an instance of `DatetimeIndex` using these timestamps. Yet simply passing

```
timestamps =  [3377536510631, 3377556564631, 3377576837400, 3377596513631, ...]
dti = DatetimeIndex(timestamps)
```

yields dates at 1970 yet they should be at 2017. Dividing them by a million to get milliseconds gives the same rsult. It seems that the input isn't as expected but I wouldn't know either how to easily set the input correctly or how to set the parameters correctly

Comment: are you sure 3377536510631 should give 2017 ? assuming this is milliseconds, it is 2077. Whats the unit of that timestamp ?

Comment: not 100% sure. It was a timestamp I got in files but no documentation was given and it's too big for milliseconds. I tried dividing it by 1, 10, 100, 1000 and 1000 000 but it remains the same result so no matter the number, there's some format or parameter that I have to provide the data

Comment: You miscalculated it. It gives the correct results at ns values. For example 1492292000000000000 gives the results: 2017-04-15 21:33:20

Comment: Your numbers gives approx 56 minutes in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp probably has a false starting time (wrong offset). This usually happens, if the time is not set correctly on the a measurement device. If you cold-start the measurement, It will probably start at time stamp 0, which is 01/01/1970.

If you know the exact time and date the measurement was started, simply subtract the .mim() value from the time stamp column and add the time stamp of the actual start time to the result.